# What does write(2) return of zero mean and will I eventually make progress (non-zero result)?

Tags: c++, sockets, blocking, file-descriptor

I have a socket over TCP that I am writing to in a C++03 program.  In some cases, I get a zero return result from write().  The write(2) man page states in part:

> On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates nothing was written). On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

So, does a zero really mean no error and I should just call write again until everything I have has been written?  In other words, should I just treat a zero just like I already do for a partial write where the number of bytes written is less than the `count` I passed to write and just keep trying until I reach a total of `count` bytes written?

I want to make sure I will not get into an infinite loop with write returning zero continuously and never making progress.  Should I be calling select() first to make sure the file descriptor is ready before calling write?  I've got blocking enabled on the file descriptor.

Comment: Are you certain you're not passing in a length of 0 when this occurs ?

Comment: Correct, I'm not passing zero length when this occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in theory, it will probably either get through or get an error eventually, I would build some safety against infinite loops, just in case.

Calling `select` to wait for the hardware may work (and it's certainly better than just looping back trying immediately again, which will almost certainly waste some CPU time - how much depends on a lot of things), but it's a [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem - some other program in your system may have got there before you and (again) filled the systems memory available to transmit through by the time you get to `write`.

So, I would do something along these lines:

```
int write_zero_count = 0; 

while(not_all_written)
{
  int res;
  res = select(...);
  ... check if we can write, etc ... 
  res = write(...);
  if (res == 0)
  {
     write_zero_count++;
     if (write_zero_count > max_zero_writes)
     {
        error("Got many writes that sent zero bytes, not good");
        .... do other stuff to log and recover from error or exit? ...
     } 
  }
  else
  {
      write_zero_count = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `write()` or `send()` in blocking mode can only return zero if you supply a zero length. This is almost certainly a programming error on your part.

The only exception would be if you are using a zero length write to prove the local TCP stack to see if there are any pending errors such as ECONNRESET.

In non-blocking mode, a zero length write means the socket send buffer is full. When you get this you should start selecting on that socket as a writefd, and retry the write when the socket becomes writable. If that succeeds, stop selecting on it as a writefd. You should normally not use writefd sets at all, as sockets are almost always ready for writing except as here, so the selector would just return immediately.

Comment: *"in non-blocking mode, a zero length write means the socket send buffer is full"* - Are you certain about that? I don't believe that is a correct statement.  If the send buffer was full, the write call would return -1 and errno would be set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: I'm not passing a zero length, so perhaps it is a bug in the Centos 4 OS.